# Adding conditions to stochastic differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Consider the following process

```
dt=0.001; s=1; tf=10;
     f[x_, y_] := 2 - x^2;
    g[x_, y_] := y - x y^2;
    sol = RandomFunction[ItoProcess[{
         \[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
          f[x[t], y[t]] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[t],
         \[DifferentialD]y[t] == g[x[t], y[t]] \[DifferentialD]t}, {x[t], 
         y[t]}, {{x, y}, {0, s}}, t, 
        w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, .1]], {0, tf, dt}];
    ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

which produces the following result

[image]

I would like to assign two conditions during the solution:

1. When `x[t]==y[t]` make `y[t]=0`

For this I've tried applying

`\[DifferentialD]y[t] ==If[x[t]==y[t],0.5\[DifferentialD]t, g[x[t], y[t]]\[DifferentialD]t`]

which did not work. It seems that this options is not valid using `ItoProcess`, so which one is?

2. Make an upper bound of `1.5` to `x[t]`, such that in the proximity of the boundary, the noise values are bounded from above.

Two examples:

- Say that `x[t]==1.5` and the noise can take values between `[-0.1, 0.1]`, then I would like that in this specific case the noise can take values between `[-0.1,0]`.
- If for example `x[t]=1.495`, I would like that the noise can take the values between `[-0.1,0.05]` etc.

Another way of treating this problem by forcing `x[t]==1.5` whenever `x[t]>1/5` (which brings us to the first part of the question). Regardless to this option, I would like the second part of the question to be addressed.

Two related questions:

[Stochastic ODE Integration problems using RandomFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186309/stochastic-ode-integration-problems-using-randomfunction)

[Boundary condition for stochastic differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27724/boundary-condition-for-stochastic-differential-equation)

Comment: Could you clarify condition 1?  Do you want to set `y[t]=0` or something with 0.5?

Comment: @ChrisK, set `y[t]==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the same trick I used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186324/6358) -- manually adding the noise to `NDSolve` instead of using `RandomFunction[ItoProcess]`.

```
σx = 0.1;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, dt] == 0,
    {x[t] -> Min[1.5, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x[t], Sqrt[dt] σx]]]}],
  WhenEvent[x[t] >= 1.5, {x[t] -> 1.5}],
  x[0] == 0, y[0] == s}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tf}][[1]];
```

The first `WhenEvent` periodically adds noise, but gives you the ability to keep `x[t] < 1.5` with `Min`.  The second `WhenEvent` is in case the deterministic dynamics makes `x[t] > 1.5` between noise injections.

Checking the results:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], 1.5} /. sol, {t, 0, tf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Addressing OP's comments:*

Note that there are two time steps in this approach: 1) a fixed time step `dt` between noise injections and 2) an automatic time step chosen by `NDSolve`.  We can see this by `ListLinePlot`ing the `InterpolatingFunction` (a trick I learned from [this answer by @MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/6358)).

```
ListLinePlot[x /. sol, PlotRange -> {{4.92, 4.93}, {1.48, 1.502}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> Line[{{4.92, 1.5}, {4.93, 1.5}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, `NDSolve` takes a few steps between noise injections (the vertical jumps).  I don't think this is actually a problem, since any numerical solution to an SDE is an approximation that introduces an artificial fixed time step.  I strongly suspect that if you make `dt` smaller, the solution will converge on a true trajectory, but this is not my area of expertise.

If the existence of two distinct time steps bothers you, then you can equate them by using a `FixedStep` method.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, dt] == 0,
    {x[t] -> Min[1.5, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x[t], Sqrt[dt] σx]]]}],
  WhenEvent[x[t] >= 1.5, {x[t] -> 1.5}],
  x[0] == 0, y[0] == s}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tf},
  StartingStepSize -> dt, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}
][[1]];

ListLinePlot[x /. sol, PlotRange -> {{2.53, 2.54}, {1.48, 1.502}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> Line[{{2.53, 1.5}, {2.54, 1.5}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see there are no intermediate steps between noise injections.  This should be the [Euler-Maruyama method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method).

I'm afraid I don't have time to figure out how to have both automatic step sizes and this flexible way to bound the solution.  It'd be great if Wolfram would add `WhenEvent` to `RandomFunction[ItoProcess]`.

If you want noise on both equations, just add an extra action to the `WhenEvent`.

*Addressing the first criterion:*

I skipped over the first criterion, to set `y[t] -> 0` when `x[t] == y[t]`.  @Xminer gave one solution in [their answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197752/6358).  Here's another that doesn't require a loose definition of equality:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]],
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, dt] == 0, {
    xold[t] -> x[t],
    x[t] -> Min[1.5, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x[t], Sqrt[dt] σx]]],
    y[t] -> If[(xold[t] < y[t] && x[t] > y[t]) || (xold[t] > y[t] && x[t] < y[t]), 0, y[t]]
  }],
  WhenEvent[x[t] >= 1.5, {x[t] -> 1.5}],
  WhenEvent[x[t] == y[t], {y[t] -> 0}],
  x[0] == 0, y[0] == s, xold[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tf}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {xold}][[1]];

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], 1.5} /. sol], {t, 0, tf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This watches for three ways `x[t] == y[t]` is possible: they're equal between noise events or at a noise event `x[t]` changed between `x[t] < y[t]` and `x[t] > y[t]` or vice versa.

Comment: I remember this answer which you gave to my previous question (mentioned in the post). It is crucial here to stick with the `RandomFunction`. Also, I would like to be more specific with the distribution of the noise where it is close to the boundary as mentioned in the post, so can not accept this answer.

Comment: Good luck with the `RandomFunction`.  Could you be more specific about how you want the noise near the boundary?  AFAIK, the noise in numerically solving an SDE is not drawn from a uniform distribution as you suggest in your post.

Comment: It can be a normal distribution from the bounded interval for example.

Comment: I think my implementation here with `Min` achieves a truncated normal distribution as you want.

Comment: @ChrisK what was your inspiration in how you manually inserted the noise here? This is going to be so helpful for making dynamic simulations in Mathematica!

Comment: @CATrevillian It separates the deterministic part from the stochastic part, which basically follows the [Euler-Maruyama method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maruyama_method) where noise is treated as normally distributed with variance `Sqrt[dt] σx`.

Comment: I think this answer is the best. (Otherwise in Table + If + Euler method).
Why do you stick to RandomFunction?
when using arbitrary stochastic processes (e.g for complex option pricing), it's pretty tough to stick to a specific function.

Comment: @ChrisK, does the noise added here is added at every time step? For this to be similar to an sde solution, the time steps must be either fixed and equal to your choice of `dt`.

Comment: @Xminer, I agree that this actually might be a good answer, however, this answer must be canonical, both `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue` have options that can change the time step, and a canonical answer must address a case in which the noise it added at everytime step, and only then, Moreover, for this kind of bouny answer, I expect a better formulation so it can be easily generalized for different types of noise, the use of several equations that each has a noise component (not just two equations with a single noise component as here).

Comment: @Xminer, another comment regarding that: what if the type of method is not chosen to be "Euler-Mayurama"? but rather Milstein or Stratanovich?

Comment: @ChrisK, please see two comments above, if you can generalize your answer to catch most of the problems I've noted  then I'll accept your answer (the time step is the most crucial in my opinion otherwise it's not really an sde scheme).

Comment: I'm not sure about Stranovich, but Milstein seems to have the same accuracy as Euler under certain conditions. 
What makes it clear is that the code is more complicated.

Comment: There are various simulation methods depending on the number of variables, their dependencies, and the types of constraints.
Isn't it a bit too broad to ask for a generalization of these?
It is good to write clearly what kind of application you want to simulate.

About The fixed step size,it is explained here.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html

Comment: @Xminer, I can accept the comments about the generalizations, however the coupling of the noise with the time step is crucial. Most methods not favor a fixed time step, and for example DAE can not be solved in mathematica with a fixed time step. Solving with `RandomFunction` Assigns noise at each time step regardless of  the method. The solution at most need to deal with this problem.

Comment: just posted the dirty example for fixed time-step and modified-Noise(literally Table+If+Euler haha)

Comment: @ChrisK, thanks for the update, looks good. I Will workout your solution and others that will hopefully come and see how it goes. My true problem is a DAE so the fixed time step is not helpful to me here, however, that is out of question's scope I've asked therefore it is fine.

Comment: @jarhead Yeah, it's hard to come up with a MWE that is simple but not too simple.  I hope we see some other answers too.

Comment: @ChrisK that is an awesome explanation, many thanks! I am glad that you provided an explanation to the underlying mathematical technique involved, I have learned a great deal because of this answer and question.

Comment: @CATrevillian TBH, I'm not an expert in SDEs and I just kind of made up this approach. It seems plausible, but please don't cite it in a paper :)

Comment: @jarhead  I wonder if anyone will post about the stochastic DAE.
Several times in the past, I've posted questions about SPDE involving local and non-local operators.(The topic was a stochastic optimal control problem.)

Comment: However, all of them have a negative rating or there is no answer to that question. also ,Mathematical problems tend to be avoided if they are difficult to understand.(https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-take-excessive-research-effort-on-behalf-of-the?rq=1)


If you do not get a satisfactory answer with this question, I strongly recommend that you use the literature based on my experience. 
Because the people here are so kind, we tend to forget the principle of studying by ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty but works.

> ```
> ClearAll["Global`*"];
> modifiedNoise[x_] := 
>   Block[{}, 
>    First@RandomVariate[
>      TruncatedDistribution[{-0.1, Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1.5 - x]]}, 
>       NormalDistribution[0, .1*\[Sqrt]dt]], 1]];
> run := Block[{}, dt = 0.02; s = 1; tf = 10; \[Epsilon] = .01;
>    f[x_, y_] := 2 - x^2;
>    g[x_, y_] := y - x y^2;
>
>    (*setting time index*)
>    numstep = IntegerPart[tf/dt];
>    timeindex = IntegerPart@Range[1, numstep];
>    Table[t[i] = 0 + dt*i, {i, timeindex}];
>    (*initial condition*)
>    t[0] = 0;
>    x[0] = 0;
>    y[0] = s;
>
>    (*Explicit Forward Euler*)
>    Table[
>     newx = 
>      x[i - 1] + dt*(f[x[i - 1], y[i - 1]]) + modifiedNoise[x[i - 1]];
>     newy = y[i - 1] + dt*(g[x[i - 1], y[i - 1]]);
>     If[Abs[newx - newy] > \[Epsilon],
>      x[i] = Min[1.5, newx];
>      y[i] = newy;,
>      x[i] = Min[1.5, newx];
>      y[i] = 0;]
>     , {i, timeindex}];
>
>    (*Result*)
>    Print[ListLinePlot[{Table[{t[i], x[i]}, {i, {0}~Join~timeindex}], 
>       Table[{t[i], y[i]}, {i, {0}~Join~timeindex}]}, 
>      PlotLabels -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}]]];
> ```

[image]

by the way,
when you add `WhenEvent[Abs[x[t] - y[t]] <= 0.03, {y[t] -> 0}]`
to [Chris's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197713/),
you got
[image]
I didn't know this way, so her/his answer is better,I think.

Comment: Nice! I wonder why `y[t]` tanks at `t==1` compared to OP's and my simulations though.

Comment: the difference between us is about constraints of y(when x[t]==y[t],y[t]=0) and volatility of noise.
From OP's definition of g[x,y],once y turned into 0 then it's clear that y keeps 0 or my mistake.

Comment: Ah I see what that first constraint means now.  I might have to revisit my answer in light of that.

Comment: It was enough to add one line for your code.
I did not know that NDSolve with WhenEvent could fully simulate SDE,really impressive!

Comment: thanks for that, I'll add it to my answer too